# How apply Filter on the basis of Custom Attribute in Order Grid Programatically

Tags: magento2, grid, filter

I have save custom_attribute(current_seller_id) in **sales_order** and **sales_order_grid** and same values in both table's columns.For save value in sales_order code is given below .I have use event `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` that dispatch order and quote

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getData('order');
        $quote = $observer->getData('quote');
        $quoteItems = $quote->getItems();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $quoteItem){
            if ($quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId() != ""){
                $items[]=$quoteItem->getCurrentSellerId();
            }
        }
        $seller_ids=implode(',',$items);
        $order->setCurrentSellerId($seller_ids);
        return $this;
    }
```

Now i want to apply condition(Filter) on the basis of own custom_attribute(current_seller_id).For example if the seller that has **current_seller_id** is **2** then just show those record in order grid which has value **2**. I will get current admin id via "\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $authSession"

Comment: am waiting answer for this question.
Nobody is there to answer my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fortunately** am giving the answer of my own question. i spend 3 Days on this question i don't want to spend time any other **developer** .

I override the function which return the array or Collection that display the orders on Sales->Order page on admin site.

make di.xml file in "app\code\VendorName\ModuleName\etc\di.xml"

and paste the code given below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider" type="VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider"/>
</config>
```

Now make the DataProvider.php File in such a way :
"VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider.php"

Paste the code given below.

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteria;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * Data Provider name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Data Provider Primary Identifier name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryFieldName;

    /**
     * Data Provider Request Parameter Identifier name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $requestFieldName;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * Provider configuration data
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $data = [];

    /**
     * @var ReportingInterface
     */
    protected $reporting;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    protected $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteria
     */
    protected $searchCriteria;
    protected $seller_order_arr;
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param ReportingInterface $reporting
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        ReportingInterface $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->primaryFieldName = $primaryFieldName;
        $this->requestFieldName = $requestFieldName;
        $this->reporting = $reporting;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->prepareUpdateUrl();
    }
    protected function searchResultToOutput(SearchResultInterface $searchResult)
    {
        $arrItems = [];

        $arrItems['items'] = [];
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            foreach ($item->getCustomAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $itemData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $attribute->getValue();
            }
            $arrItems['items'][] = $itemData;
            $arrItems['totalRecords'] = $searchResult->getTotalCount();
    }
                return $arrItems;
    }
        public function getTotalOrder($ordersize){
         return  sizeof($ordersize);
        }
        public function getSearchCriteria()
        {
            if (!$this->searchCriteria) {
                $this->searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
                $this->searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->name);
            }
            return $this->searchCriteria;
        }

        /**
         * Get data
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public
        function getData()
        {
            return $this->searchResultToOutput($this->getSearchResult());
        }

        /**
         * Get config data
         *
         * @return array
         */


        /**
         * Set data
         *
         * @param mixed $config
         * @return void
         */

        /**
         * Returns Search result
         *
         * @return SearchResultInterface
         */

          public function getSearchResult()
        {
            return $this->reporting->search($this->getSearchCriteria());
        }

}
```

Comment: hello, I have similar requirement. Can you please explain where you use that filed ? I need to filter with customer email. Base on login user need to display particular order only that match with current user email.